# Get value of variable in javascript, which is combination of other two variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created variables in java script via loop as

```
var option1="some value 1";
var option2="some value 2";
var option3="some value 3";
```

Now If `val=2` (val depends upon user input it may 1,2 or 3). I have to print `option1`, `option2`, `option3` accordingly.

```
var finalopt="option"+val;
  alert(finalopt);
```

now output is (`option2`)
I want output as (some value 2) because value of option `2` is some value `2`.

Comment: Just declare it as an array and it works fine. ['some value 1', 'some value 2', 'some value 2']. alert([val]);

Comment: it could be much easy if declared as properties of single obj and access as  obj["option" + val] but if you want it as in que multiple variables use the global object window as window["option" + val]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine them in the object

```
var obj = {
   option1:"some value 1",
   option2:"some value 2",
   option3:"some value 3"
}
```

and use `[]` syntax for accessing properties

```
var finalopt="option"+val;
console.log(obj[finalopt]);
```

Code snippet

```js
var obj = {
   option1:"some value 1",
   option2:"some value 2",
   option3:"some value 3"
}

var val = prompt('Input 1, 2 or 3');

var finalopt="option"+val;
console.log(obj[finalopt]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window` object to get variable value by its name:

```
window[finalopt];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('option'+val);
```

It works, but other solutions are better.